# Convert string to json in order to pass in requests.post

Tags: python, flask, request

I have 2 strings which are stored in variables

```
headers = str('{"Authorization":"'+auth+'"}')
otp = str('{"otp":"'+otp+'"}')
```

Using ast library I convert them to dictionary.

```
data = ast.literal_eval(otp)
head = ast.literal_eval(headers)

Output : 

{'otp': '0910'}
{'Authorization': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIU'}
```

But when I pass them to:

```
response = requests.post(url, params=data, headers = head)
```

I get this message

```
{'status': 'failure', 'message': 'invalid json'}
```

I understand this is a problem of single and double quotes but I am bit confused how to change single quotes to double quotes.

I tried using **json.dumps()** but this returns string which is not acceptable.

Please help.

Comment: It seems that the error comes from the server not from requests, can you verify what format the server is accepting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json` instead of `params`

```
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=head)
```

Comment: Works nicely.. Thanks!!